# Map with unordered tuple as key

Tags: haskell, dictionary, tuples

I have a mapping between a tuple with both parts of the same type and a Int.

```
Map (a,a) Int
```

Independent of the ordering of the `as` in the tuple I want later to be able to get it out of the map.

```
lookup (2,1) map == lookup (1,2) map
```

Is this possible without inserting the tuple twice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make the key `(max a b, min a b)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can just sort the tuple and then use this to inseet the tuples (and search too):

```
sortTup :: (Ord a) => (a, a) -> (a, a)
sortTup (a, b) = (min a b, max a b)
```

Using it you would look something like this:

```
Prelude Data.Map> let a = Map.fromList [(sortTup (2,1), 5]
Prelude Data.Map> lookup (sortTup (1,2))
5
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
import Control.Applicative

mylookup :: (Ord a) => (a,a) -> Map (a,a) Int -> Maybe Int
mylookup (x,y) m = lookup (x,y) m <|> lookup (y,x) m
```